# geometry object's created in Blender lose details in SceneKit

Tags: import, scenekit, blender

I'm using Blender to design a custom geometry object which will be used in my sceneKit scene. I import it using childNodeWithName:. I experience a significant lost in accuracy of object representation. In blender it looks terrific(see the upper picture), but in sceneKit it is full of sharp edges(bottom image). What must be done to avoid such lost of details? I'm importing a cube with smooth edges so I'm guessing that shouldn't be to hard to represent in SceneKit.

[image]

[image]

EDIT: I added visual representation of my problem.

Comment: You have described this using the wrong medium. https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/A_picture_is_worth_a_thousand_words

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[image]

I must type at least 30 characters in order to post this screenshot.

Answer (score 1):

you probably have a smooth modifier (or something like that) that you have to bake (apply) before you export your model.

Comment: Description of my cube: 1. I went to modifiers->add modiifer--> subdivision surface. 2. Shading-->checked Smooth. 3. Parts of my cube are extruded using Extrude individual, 4. I'm using 2 different materials on my cube. Basically, it would be great if I could export the cube as it appears in Blender. What things and how do I need to apply before exporting?